# can we update in app purchase product list in live app

Tags: ios, web-services, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app in which i am populating a list of books list form our server and then allowing the user to purchase those books.

My question for this is as for this i have to use in app purchase so when app will not be live then we will be adding in app purchase product on ituneconnect for the added books. BUt when app will be live then can be add new products in itune for our app so that i can add new books in my web server.

if yes then i thought i can get this by following approach

give the book id same as in app purchase product id in itunes so then when a user will click on the book then i can purchase the product by using bookid which will be same as in app purchase product id.

so by this was on the live app i will be adding new books and the bookid and the in app purchase product id for that book will be same.

Is that approach is fine and can be add products in live app?

please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

I Think yes you can if your product list is coming from server. and no if you use hard coded product in your code

For more detail you can check FAQ in iTune Connect.